# Что лучше RGB или grayscale многопороговая сегментация?

Tags: color, сегментация

Я занимаюсь сегментацией изображений полога леса. И не могу определится между RGB и grayscale многопороговой сегментацией? Существуют ли какие-то специальные критерии для этого? Можно разъяснить пожалуйста? В чем плюс и минусы при выборе этих двух методов?

Comment: grayscale - это усредненная (с определенными весами) информация RGB. Если смотреть в RGB, то может оказаться, что в каком-то из цветовых каналов больше нужной вам информации (большая контрастность между областями, которые вам нужно различать). Можно взять RGB, взять только нужный вам канал, преобразовать только его в grayscale, и уже с этой информацией работать.